# How would I order the brand divs depending on language selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I need to achieve the following:
On change of language at the top of the page, brand divs (strips with paper aeroplanes in) change order to show sites that are in that language first. This will be on a wordpress site and utilising a translation plugin. I am a little unsure where to start, I know a little about onclick events but my knowledge is really limited. The current dev site can be found here: http://atsreisen.eighty3.co.uk/de/

Comment: There isn't enough information to give a proper answer.  Some WP translation plugins operate by creating editable duplicate pages, for example, so re-arranging your `div` might be as simple as editing the appropriate translation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It looks like that is the case for this plugin. Only thing is I can't seem to see where the german page is generated. When I look in the back end it has no content and is just pulling the english version in

Comment: Most of the translate plugins that operate that that I have experienced usually have a toggle on the primary page to show you the various translation options.  Look for a dropdown menu on the right-hand side or some element for checking the translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding perfectly, you need to attach the language at the top to the brand divs. You can do that by adding data-lang attribute in your html and ids to your links. (data-something) is a way for you to create your custom attributes to use in jQuery.

```
<a class="lang" href="#0" id="german">German</a>
<a class="lang" href="#0" id="english">English</a>
<div id="container">
  <div data-lang="german">This is a brand div</div>
  <div data-lang="english">This is another brand div</div>
  <div data-lang="english">This is an English brand div</div>
</div>
```

Then in jQuery you can do this:

```
//variables (caching)
var langLink = $('.lang');
var langId;
var dataLang;

langLink.on('click', function(event) {
  // this part to prevent the page from refreshing when the link is clicked
  event.preventDefault();
  // get the clicked links Ids, hence $(this)
  langId = $(this).attr('id');
  // go up to a parent the links and divs share here it's the body
  // then finding the divs that has data-lang matching the links id
  dataLang = $(this).parent('body').find('div[data-lang="' + langId + '"]');
  // a temporary storage to store all the divs that match the language clicked
  var temp = [];
  // pushing the found divs to the temp storage
  temp.push(dataLang);
  // removing them from the dom
  dataLang.remove();
  // and finally looping through the temp storage array and prepending it to the container
  for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
    $('#container').prepend(temp[i]);
  }
});
```

This is how I would go about it but I'm sure there are other ways to do this.
If you want to see it in action try this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/euv2nygv/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using wordpress, you can achieve this in many ways. The simplest way, is to modify the wordpress theme header (ideally through a child theme), and add an "if condition" to detect the current wordpress language and add a class to the body accordingly; you can do it by using wordpress `get_locale()` function. Then you may need a little javascript, or ideally jQuery, to get the brands divs and reorder them regarding the body class.